# Apache JMeter:Why am I getting an issue in the proxy connection for the recording controller?

Tags: windows, jmeter

I need some help to solve one issue based on this module Performance Testing of a Web application using JMeter. To finish my project in JMeter I have to record website actions using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to create I used Templates( I use lenovo windows 10).
I had an issue to record some requests, but I found a solution:

1. import ApacheRootCErtificate
2. change proxy server, on manual proxy set up, enter localhost and port:8080 and save it( same port I entered to HTTP Test Script Recorder).
   It started recording, but after some seconds my chrome stopped working and gave an error: "no internet.
   there is something wrong with the proxy server, or the address is incorrect
   -checking the proxy address
   -running windows network diagnostics"
   I tried to fix this problem by turning off the manual proxy set up and it worked, but I am not able to use Test Script Recorder.
   Can you help to find a solution to these issues?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you're behind a corporate proxy, there is a [special chapter of the JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) which explains how to configure JMeter to make it aware of the upstream proxy server:

> If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter[.bat] file from a command line with the following parameters:
>
> -E [proxy scheme to use - optional - for non-http]
>
> -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
>
> -P [proxy server port]
>
> -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>
> -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> jmeter -E https -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
> ```

Also you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) for recording a JMeter test, in this case you won't need to worry about proxies and certificates.